# wordpress wpautop not working with wpalchemy repeating fields

Tags: wordpress

I can get this to work with non repeating fields with the first example, however with the 2nd example using repeating fields I cannot get the wpauto function to work.

```
<?php echo "<strong>Paragraph</strong>".wpautop($meta['paragraph']).""; ?>
```

This is the closest I've gotten... I know the first part of the function before the wpautop is printing it and the wpautop is pretty much doing nothing as of yet.

```
<?php
        global $index_accordian_repeat;                        
        ?>


            <?php if($index_accordian_repeat->have_value('panels')):?>


            <dl class="accordion">                              
                <?php while( $index_accordian_repeat->have_fields('panels') ) : ?>

                       <!--title --><dt><a href=""><?php $index_accordian_repeat->the_value('header'); ?></a></dt>
                       <!--link --><dd><?php $index_accordian_repeat->the_value('link'); ?><br />
                       <!--content --><?php $my_meta = $index_accordian_repeat->the_value('');
                                        echo wpautop($my_meta['content']); ?></dd>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </dl>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it always the most simple answer!? I was asking for the_value which would print it and then I asked in another way that just gave me an array. But this is what made it work...

```
<?php $content = $index_accordian_repeat->get_the_value('content');?> <?php echo wpautop($content); ?>
```

I need to return the value but not print it and then take the value and echo it. PHEW!